# MATLAB commands to find from the path of an input, the corresponding input in the parent subsystems

Tags: matlab, model, simulink

I have a simulink model with subsystems to which are linked inputs and outputs. I would like using MATLAB commands to find from the path of an input, the corresponding input in the parent subsystems.

Example :

[My simulink model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXfCb.png)

Here I want to find "RootInput" using the path of "CurrentInput" using matlab commands.

I have tried using the ports but it doesn't work in all cases and on the Mathworks doc I haven't found a way to do it. Is there a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find all blocks name by using (assuming you have a model in name of 'a.slx')

```
b=get_param('a/Subsystem','PortConnectivity') % this will give you connection information of SubSystem.
d=get_param(b(1).SrcBlock, 'BlockType') 

e=get_param(b(1).SrcBlock, 'Name')
f=get_param(b(1).SrcBlock, 'Ports')
h=get_param(b(1).SrcBlock, 'PortConnectivity')
i=get_param(b(1).SrcBlock, 'OutputSignalNames')
```

you can reach many parameters by using get_param().
related functions you can use are listed in https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/get_param.html